# How do you implement content-disposition as an attachment for django_weasyprint package?

Tags: django, pdf, django-views, weasyprint

Using the `django_weasyprint` (class-based view implementation) package to generate a pdf.

I'm able to generate a pdf in the browser but have trouble setting up a open/save-as dialog box pop-up feature. I know I have to set content-disposition equal to attachment (I think) but I'm struggling doing so.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from django_weasyprint import WeasyTemplateResponseMixin


class ArticleView(DetailView):
    # vanilla Django DetailView
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'


class ArticlePrintView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, ArticleView):
    # output of DetailView rendered as PDF
    pdf_stylesheets = [
        settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/app.css',
    ]
```

I'd like to have the open/save-as dialog box to pop-up automatically.

Comment: Yes you need an actual pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [code for the `WeasyTemplateResponseMixin`](https://github.com/fdemmer/django-weasyprint/blob/master/django_weasyprint/views.py#L93-L109) - there is the option to set `pdf_filename` on the class, and if you do that, then the `Content-Disposition` header will be set with this file name, so that the browser opens a download/save dialog for the file. Something like this:

class ArticlePrintView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, ArticleView):

```
pdf_filename = 'my-pdf.pdf'
```

If you need to determine the file name dynamically then you can override the `get_pdf_filename` method to do that:

```
def get_pdf_filename(self):
    return 'some-file.pdf'
```